# Jersey Rest webservice redirecting to the same page

Tags: java, jsp, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have a simple rest webservice that will be used to load a page. Once the page is loaded the same page will be displayed with a confirmation msg or error msg being displayed.

Im using the using the below code to load it ....

jsp page:-

```
<form action="rest/file/upload" method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <br> <label>Username: &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</label><input type="text"
        placeholder="Username" name="username"> <br> <br>
    <label>Password:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</label><input type="text"
        placeholder="Password" name="password"> <br> <br>

    <hr>
    <p>
        Select a file : <input type="file" name="file" size="45" />
    </p>
    <br> <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Upload" />
    <c:out value="${obj}" />
    <!-- ${obj} -->
</form>
```

controller

```
@Path("/file")
public class FileUploadService {
    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Viewable uploadFile(
        @Context HttpServletRequest request,@Context HttpServletResponse response,
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail,
        @FormDataParam("username") String username,
        @FormDataParam("password") String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, URISyntaxException {


        response.setHeader("Location", "/");

        return new Viewable("/index.jsp",null);
```

web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Once I click the form the file is loaded and it takes back to the index.jsp page, but the location of the page is set to. RESTFileUpload is the program name.

```
http://localhost:8080/RESTFileUpload/rest/
```

but I want it to be

```
http://localhost:8080/RESTFileUpload/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know much (or really anything) about the MVC features Jersey, but another option is to just use a redirect. You can simply use [`Response.seeOther(URI)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#seeOther%28java.net.URI%29). This will send out a ["303 See Other"](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) with the `Location` header. The browser should send another request for this page. The method might look something like

```
public Response getRedirect(@Context ServletContext context) {
    UriBuilder builder = UriBuilder.fromPath(context.getContextPath());
    builder.path("index.jsp");
    return Response.seeOther(builder.build()).build();       
}
```

This will redirect to `/contextPath/index.jsp` (or in other words the `index.jsp` path located in the webapp root)

As an aside, if you are familiar with Javascript/jQuery at all, there are other [file upload options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax) that don't involve the redirect.

---

### UPDATE

Just to show that this works fine

```
@Path("/redirect")
public class RedirectResource { 
    @GET
    public Response getRedirect(@Context ServletContext context) {
        UriBuilder builder = UriBuilder.fromPath(context.getContextPath());
        builder.path("index.html");
        return Response.seeOther(builder.build()).build();

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The root is still taken as RESTFileUpload/rest and with above commands it points to RESTFileUpload/rest/RESTFileUpload/index.jsp

Comment: It's possible you are doing something incorrectly. You can see from the end that the `root` is not used. Why you have the extra part in front I don't know. Are you still returning `Viewable`? It should simply be the `Response` as shown in the example